# Change the size of an <a> element to fit parent <span>

Tags: html, css, href, bxslider, sizing

I'm currently working on a site that requires slideshows, and I'm using the bxSlider script. The way it works right now is the code finds a `span id="next_1"` and `span id="prev_1'` and inserts a `<a href=''>+</a>`. I've got it setup so the `span` elements are white boxes, and when hovered will go black. The only clickable element is the **+** inside the `span`. I'm wondering how to resize the `<a>` element to fit the entire `span` element.

[**Here's my code.**](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/Ciqae)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS you can select the `<a>` tag and add `display: block` and `padding: 8px` and remove those properties from the `.button` class. Hope it helps you. Thanks.